# Is it possible to run a Windows Visual C++ program in Linux?

Tags: linux, wine, c++

I am trying to run [this](http://www.ccsl.carleton.ca/~jamuir/rdtscpm1.pdf) code on PAGE 7. of this document, and successfully ran it on Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 for Windows. The problem is that I need to get this code working on linux. I read up a bit, and found Wine could be helpful in linux to run the .exe file generated from Visual studio compilation. I installed Wine and ran the .exe file, but it gives an error:

```
snehil@ubuntu:~/Desktop/wine$ wine b2
err:module:import_dll Library MSVCR100D.dll (which is needed by    
L"Z:\\home\\snehil\\Desktop\\wine\\b2.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for   
L"Z:\\home\\snehil\\Desktop\\wine\\b2.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Please give me your valuable suggestion/pointers/references/advice on how can I get the .exe file running on Linux by looking at the code.

Comment: download or copy MSVCR100D.dll from your windows and place where the .exe is present in linux

Comment: Another option could be to recompile the same code in Linux, using gcc

Comment: Msvcr*d.dll are debug versions of the dll.  Try rebuilding in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment from Chad above:

*Msvcr*d.dll* is the debug version of the dll. Try rebuilding the application in release mode